# Is there any way in which we can render DOM after fetching data in ReactJS like AngularJS does?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In angularJS whenever there is a change in the scope variable it automatically changes the DOM. Also if there is delay in fetching data from ajax call, it will render after fetching the data. Is there any way in which this kind of issue be solved in ReactJS?

I tried below code, but it always shows the 'loading...' div

```
import React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

export default class Article extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    console.log(props);
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: []
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs.json`)
      .then(res => {
        const posts = res.data.data.children.map(obj => obj.data);
        this.setState({ posts });
        console.log(posts);
      });
  }
  render() {
    const { posts } = this.props;
    if (posts) {
      const { title } = this.props;
      const { articleName } = this.props;
      console.log(this.state.posts);

      return (
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <p>This is generated from Article Component from Article JS { title }</p>
            <a className="btn btn-default" href="#">More Info</a>
            <div>
            {posts}
            </div>
          </div>
      );
  }
  return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
}
```

Comment: can you console.log(posts) in your axios callback and add the result to your code.

Comment: It is an array of objects from the result. I cannot show the output because my componentDidMount is executed only once even after modifying the function

Comment: It is a property of componentDidMount that it executs only once. You can see the result in chrome logs

Comment: Check redux and its documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that you have that problem is that you are using props to check for posts

```
const { posts } = this.props;
```

and this is always null because you don't have props filled this posts bud state
 so change that line to:

```
const posts = this.state.posts;
```

also in:

```
if(posts) {
       const postList = posts.map((post, index) =>
      <div key={index}>post.Title</div>);// Title (if title is part of json)
    return (
          <div className="col-md-4">
            <h4>{title}</h4>
            <p>This is generated from Article Component from Article JS { title }</p>
            <a className="btn btn-default" href="#">More Info</a>
            <div>
            {postList}
            </div>
          </div>
      );

}
```

Comment: then I get this error

"Uncaught (in promise) Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {contest_mode, banned_by, domain, subreddit, selftext_html, selftext, likes, suggested_sort, user_reports, secure_media, saved, id, gilded, secure_media_embed, clicked, report_reasons, author, media, name, score, approved_by, over_18, removal_reason, hidden, thumbnail, subreddit_id, edited, link_flair_css_class, author_flair_css_class, downs, mod_reports, archived, media_embed, is_self, hide_score, spoiler, permalink, ...."

Comment: You should map on the posts that you get from service after if condition :
    const postsList = posts.map((post, index) =>
      <div key={index}>post.Title</div>);// Title or the props from json
and then change {posts} to {postsList}